# How to bind string value to to each element in list

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have list generated using range function..a

example

`10-15`

```
[10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

now want to add 'eth1/' to each value to list

output should be

```
eth1/10,eth1/11,eth1/12,eth1/13,eth1/14,eth1/15
```

pls help...

Comment: You can use `+` to concatenate two string here how can you do it with list comprehension -  `['eth1/'+ str(item) for item in list_input]`

Comment: you can use f-strings `[f'eth1/{x}' for x in lst]`

Comment: @deadshot ...thanks.. I will check

Answer (score 0):

You can create another list, like this:

```
start = int(input())
end = int(input())
digit = [x for x in range(start,end+1)]
result = []
for i in digit:
    result.append('eth1/' + str(i))
print(result)
```

if `start = 10` and `end = 15` output:

```
['eth1/10', 'eth1/11', 'eth1/12', 'eth1/13', 'eth1/14', 'eth1/15']
```

Comment: thanks..but if my range is user defined from command promt any

Comment: like 10-12 ,  34 -56 any...how to do then

Comment: @Pradip I changed it